# Fill the height of a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to fill the  top and bottom of a UICollectionViewCell. I dont want to stretch the the image either or have it get cut off.
The ImageView content view is "Aspect Fit" but when I change to "Aspect fill" it cuts out the image.... How do I do this to fit every phone?

**Aspect Fit**

[image]

**Aspect Fill**

[image]

Below is my code:

UIViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    
    var imgArr = ["Alexandra Daddario",
                    "Angelina Jolie" ,
                    "Anne Hathaway" ,
                    "Dakota Johnson" ,
                    "Emma Stone" ,
                    "Emma Watson" ,
                    "Halle Berry" ,
                    "Jennifer Lawrence" ,
                    "Jessica Alba" ,
                    "Scarlett Johansson" ]

    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
    
}


extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imgArr.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? DataCollectionViewCell
        cell?.img.image = UIImage(named:imgArr[indexPath.row])
        return cell!
        
    }
    
}
```

UICollectionViewCell

```
import UIKit

class DataCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var img: UIImageView!
    
    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `Aspect Fill` on your image view?

Comment: Yes updated question with both options. You can see that Aspect Fill cuts the image...

Comment: Of course, it will fill the available space but keeping the image in the same aspect ratio. I think you should show what it is that you are trying to achieve as currently it is unclear.

Comment: I want it to fill the size of the cell without cutting or stretching on every device.

Comment: This is unclear. If you want to fill the whole cell, you either have to stretch the image or cut some parts. What other option do you see?